# Can't access SDL library when trying to compile using g++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, sdl

I'm getting started with SDL -- that is, I have no experience and am basically just trying to get something to compile at this point.

I have a basic program:

```
#include "sdl/SDL.h"

int main(){
        // Fire up SDL, this starts all subsystems; audio video etc.
        if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            exit(1); 
        }
    // Now Shut it down
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    return 0;
}
```

And I have this which I'm typing into the terminal:

```
g++ 'sdl-config --cflags --libs' -o sdltest sdltest.cpp
```

where `sdltest.cpp` is the name of the file.

This gives me the error:

```
g++: error: stl-config --cflags --libs: No such file or directory
```

Now, previously I have (I think) installed SDL like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

The issue might have to do with a faulty installation -- this might not be the package I was supposed to install, or I might be completely forgetting a step here.

I'm using Ubuntu, and compiling using g++, if it wasn't apparent from context.

Comment: Looks like a spelling error and the fact that you're using single quotes and not backticks, try `g++ \`sdl-config --cflags --libs\` -o sdltest sdltest.cpp`

Comment: Sweet, that worked.  Thanks!  For reference when I inevitably try googling this again and find it, I also had to move the `sdl-config...etc.` to the end of the compile statement, remove sdl/ from the include statement, and sudo apt-get install libsdl1-2.dev to make it work.  Also, the test program doesn't actually do anything, so I tested it with this:  http://friedspace.com/SDLTest.c

Comment: Yeah sorry I missed that too, when linking static libs you'll need to put the link flags at the end.